# Prevent Firefox Reload Confirmation Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, reload, onbeforeunload

I have a form that users submit, it checks against a few web services, and when one of the APIs returns an error I refresh the form once using JS, maintaining POST data.

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
            if(!window.location.hash) {
            window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
            window.location.reload();
            }
        }
</script>
```

It works fine in Chrome/Safari. I've tried variations of below, with no luck partly because I'm appending to URI.

window.location=window.location;
window.location.href = window.location;

Any help would be appreciated as I've spent many hours on this. Thank you.

Comment: Submit the original form using GET instead of POST. POST indicates an operation that will change server resources, hence the warning. GET implies a read-only operation that can be repeated with no consequences

Comment: I know it's one option but I want to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? (I ask because your reason may suggest alternatives)

Comment: My reason is not important but thanks for the initial suggestion.

Comment: Welcome, but that's kinda like saying "I can't hammer this nail with a screwdriver" "Why not use a hammer?" "I don't want to". If your reason is because there's info you don't want in the url, it may be possible to make a POST form redirect to a GET url with an Id that can be refreshed. If it's because you don't know how to url-encode GET parameters, we can show you how. If there's some existing form logic that can't be altered, maybe iframes are an option. If you're not willing to provide more information then all we can say is "The answer is 'no'. You're using the wrong tool for the job"

Answer (score 0):

this.location.reload(); will work without asking confirmation